# Cannot access class variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I started using typescript together with angularjs. I have written a simple class that is responsible for drag and drop behavior (or will be in future). But right now in my handleDragEnd function when I access canvas element I get error

> Cannot read property of undefined

Below is my code - if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong I would be grateful.

```
class ToolBox {
private canvas;

constructor(canvas)
{
    this.canvas = canvas;

    $(".beacon").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        start: this.handleDragStart,
        stop: this.handleDragEnd
    });        
}

handleDragStart()
{
    console.log('Drag Started!');
}

handleDragEnd()
{              
    var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(event.e);

    console.log('Drag End!');  
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: In case you haven't already. You should check out [parameter properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Classes#parameter-properties). They're a nice syntax that will remove a few lines in your code by doing `constructor(private canvas)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since class methods are defined on `ToolBox.prototype`, the value of `this` is getting lost when you pass in the methods directly.

Change:

```
start: this.handleDragStart,
stop: this.handleDragEnd
```

To:

```
start: () => this.handleDragStart(),
stop: () => this.handleDragEnd()
```

That will preserve the value of `this` by calling the methods on the instance.

Comment: that is perfect! It will make my life easier :)

Comment: you are a diamond mate!